# Sharp sweet smell

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

What does "sharp" in sharp-sweet mean ? It's referred to a "smell of sweat" in my text. Does that mean more like "acrid" unpleasant irritating or "penetrating" "powerful" ? I really can't get the meaning of this word.

Comment: Merriam-Webster merely gives the synonym 'acrid' for this sense of 'sharp'. How does M-W define this sense of 'acrid'? // Not an 'answer', as I can't find a supporting reference, but 'acrid' seems more extreme than 'sharp' to me. I can see myself gingerly testing a citrus fruit with a sharp smell.

Comment: "sharp-sweet" is made up.  The author made it up. Something can be both sharp and sweet. Or is it: a sharp, sweet smell? Please adjust your punctuation.

Comment: What;s the full context?

Comment: Stinks so good...

Comment: Sharp has multiple meanings. You'll need to actually read the text and think about what's causing the smell.

Comment: Sugar, spice, and everything nice, strawberry lemonade, SweeTart Ropes and/or Sour Patch Kids, and stank feet.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the reference. The entire sentence is

> The house was saturated with this slight sharp-sweet smell that girls have when dancing and sweating.

If it's this, it would be more about the power of the smell, rather than it's acridity. In my humble opinion anyway.